# Homework, linked list bubble sort

Tags: c, linked-list, bubble-sort

i have a little problem with a homework, where i have to work with linked list, the problem is the sorting function, i choosed the bubblesort algorithm, here is a piece of code.

```
void BubbleSort(PrikazStruct **Seznam) {
    int Prohozeno = NULL;
    int Value_1, Value_2;

    PrikazStruct *AktualniPrikaz = *Seznam;
    PrikazStruct *Temp = AktualniPrikaz->Dalsi;

    Value_1 = AktualniPrikaz->Jmeno[0];
    Value_2 = AktualniPrikaz->Dalsi->Jmeno[0];

    do {
        Prohozeno = 1;

        while (AktualniPrikaz->Dalsi != NULL) {
            if (Value_1 < Value_2) {
                ProhodCleny(AktualniPrikaz, AktualniPrikaz->Dalsi);
                Prohozeno = 0;
            }

            Value_1 = AktualniPrikaz->Jmeno[0];
            AktualniPrikaz = AktualniPrikaz->Dalsi;
            Value_2 = AktualniPrikaz->Jmeno[0];

        }

    } while (!Prohozeno);

    return;
}
```

i cant realize why, it does not sort the list properly, here is the structure swap function

```
void ProhodCleny(PrikazStruct *S1, PrikazStruct *S2) {
    PrikazStruct *Temp = (PrikazStruct *) malloc(sizeof(PrikazStruct));

    Temp->ID = S1->ID;
    strcpy(Temp->Jmeno, S1->Jmeno);
    strcpy(Temp->Prijmeni, S1->Prijmeni);
    Temp->Castka = S1->Castka;
    strcpy(Temp->Popis, S1->Popis);
    Temp->Obdobi = S1->Obdobi;
    strcpy(Temp->stringObdobi, S1->stringObdobi);
    strcpy(Temp->JePlatba, S1->JePlatba);

    S1->ID = S2->ID;
    strcpy(S1->Jmeno, S2->Jmeno);
    strcpy(S1->Prijmeni, S2->Prijmeni);
    S1->Castka = S2->Castka;
    strcpy(S1->Popis, S2->Popis);
    S1->Obdobi = S2->Obdobi;
    strcpy(S1->stringObdobi, S2->stringObdobi);
    strcpy(S1->JePlatba, S2->JePlatba);

    S2->ID = Temp->ID;
    strcpy(S2->Jmeno, Temp->Jmeno);
    strcpy(S2->Prijmeni, Temp->Prijmeni);
    S2->Castka = Temp->Castka;
    strcpy(S2->Popis, Temp->Popis);
    S2->Obdobi = Temp->Obdobi;
    strcpy(S2->stringObdobi, Temp->stringObdobi);
    strcpy(S2->JePlatba, Temp->JePlatba);

    free(Temp);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Please make a [mcve].

Comment: short example input, desired output and actual output would help I guess

Comment: Oh sure, the output should be C, B, A but for some reason i've got output C, A, B and im sure the if statement was executed 2nd times.

Input is A, B, C

Answer (score 2):

You need to reset the working pointer in each outer loop:

```
    Prohozeno = 1;               /* after this line */
    AktualniPrikaz = *Seznam;    /*   add this line */
```

also the code is swapping the contents of the nodes, rather than changing the node links to accomplish the sort. I'm not sure if this is allowed for you class assignment.

If you need to change the links instead of using a bubble sort (swapping nodes via links is complicated) it would be simpler to create a new empty list such as:

```
PrikazStruct *Sorted = NULL;    /* this will be sorted list */
```

then remove nodes from the original list one at a time and insert them into the to be sorted list in order. Other methods such as bottom up merge sort would be faster, but way beyond what you would expect for this type of class assignment.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists

It would be faster still to create an array of pointers to node, sort the array of pointers, then relink the list based on the sorted array of pointers, but this takes O(n) space, and it's not a linked list sort.

Answer (score 0):

Your swap function is copying the complete contents of the nodes. That's going to be very inefficient, very specific to the content of the nodes, and anyone holding pointers to those nodes will be very surprised when the content changes. A good sort algorithm only needs to know the sorting criteria.

Instead, it should be leaving the content of the nodes alone and relinking them in the list. As you've probably noticed, with a single linked list to "bubble up" you need the two nodes and the previous one. Instead, of bubbling smaller items up, push the larger ones down.

Here's the basic algorithm.

```
while( changed ) {
    changed = 0;

    /* I believe you forgot this part */
    q = top;
    p = top->next;

    while( p->next != NULL ) {
        /* push bigger items down */
        if( p->data > p->next->data ) {
            q->next = list_switch( p, p->next );
            changed = 1;
        }

        q = p;

        if( p->next != NULL ) {
            p = p->next;
        }
    }
}
```

And the swap function is very simple.

```
LIST *list_switch( LIST *l1, LIST *l2 )
{
    l1->next = l2->next;
    l2->next = l1;
    return l2;
}
```

For more, see this [Linked List Bubble Sort example](http://faculty.salina.k-state.edu/tim/CMST302/study_guide/topic7/bubble.html).

Comment: I also thank you, but i have problem, when i call the bubblesort function for 2nd time, the output is broken, for example, for the 1st time its ABC, and for 2nd its only A

Comment: @スラフロスチ Sorry, there's any number of things which could be causing that. Without a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I can't say what. I'd suggest using a memory checker like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).